# Laravel ErrorException - Invalid path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have my laravel website on a shared hosting.

After syncing the remote files with PhpStorm and run composer update i receive

```
"file_put_contents(C:\xampp\public_html\mydomain.com\storage\framework\views/558703d19442567af4246eafaed8012c37ed6c26.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Version of laravel is 5.6.22

Any ideea how to fix this ?

Comment: That is a cached version of one of your blades (file.blade.php), just delete them before sync, they will be remade when viewed again.

Comment: if you have `shell` `ssh` access to your hosing then goto your laravel directory and run `php artisan clear-compile` `php artisan config-cache`